# Azure Linux VM stuck on loading - Unable to access serial console

Tags: linux, azure

I got a linux VM in Azure and from the screenshot via the Boot Diagnostics menu, I can see that it gives the following message :

"**you are in emergency mode.....press Enter for maintenance or Press CTRL D to continue**"

I tried to access the VM using the serial console and it connects to the console and I see a message as below :

**"Connected to the serial port of the VM
If no loginprompt is displayed press ENTER"**

But.....despite pressing Enter nothing happens! Ive tried rebooting, restarting etc but still stuck

Answer (score 0):

For the error **you are in emergency mode.....press Enter for maintenance or Press CTRL D to continue**

The emergency mode sometimes means either your file system is corrupted or you created a new partition or edited existing partition.

Please perform a file system check using below  command :

```
fsck.ext4 /dev/sda3
```

where sda3 can be your partition and if you are using ext3 file system, change the command as follows:

```
fsck.ext3 /dev/sda3
```

Cycle through the SDAs by changing the last number in the sda to see which file system has problems.

Ex: sda1, sda2, sda3, sda4, and so on

For the  error **Connected to the serial port of the VM If no loginprompt is displayed press ENTER**

This issue occurs when the serial console connection is successfully made to the virtual machine, but the virtual machine is not configured for input/output on the serial port.

To ensure your Linux virtual machine works with Azure serial console, please follow the guidance: Create and upload an Ubuntu Linux VHD in Azure - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-ubuntu for the distribution you are using. Specifically you will need to perform these steps from the preceding link:

Modify the kernel boot line in GRUB or GRUB2 to include the following parameters. This will also ensure all console messages are sent to the first serial port, which can assist Azure support with debugging issues:

```
console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200 rootdelay=300
```

In addition to the above, it is recommended to remove the following parameters if they exist:

```
rhgb quiet crashkernel=auto
```

Graphical and quiet boot are not useful in a cloud environment where we want all the logs to be sent to the serial port. The crashkernel option may be left configured if desired, but note that this parameter will reduce the amount of available memory in the VM by 128MB or more, which may be problematic on the smaller VM sizes.

Reference :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347808/ubuntu-gives-message-welcome-to-emergency-mode
https://github.com/Microsoft/azserialconsole/blob/master/Known_Issues/Hitting_enter_does_nothing.md

Comment: ok seemed there was an issue with the VHD